# Java socket closed not detected

Tags: java, sockets

I've written a little Server/Client Application. Here is the code

```
try 
{
   OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);   
   System.out.println("clientsocketstatus connected: " + clientSocket.isConnected());
   System.out.println("clientsocketstatus closed: " + clientSocket.isClosed());
   oos.writeObject(keepAliveNW); 
} 
   catch(Exception e) 
{ 
   e.printstacktrace(); 
}
```

Now when I disable the NIC in Windows and reenable netstat shows no open connections between my PC1 and PC2. 
When now my Client tries to send a keepAliveNW Object there should be an exception, but there is none. I wiresharked. There arrives no data on the Server. I also Wiresharked on the Client. The Keep-Alive Packet is send, but there is never any TCP ACK Paket, so Java should detect that there is something going wrong. When the connection is fully established there is a TCP ACK Paket after the keep-Alive Paket as it should be.
So how could I detect that the connection has been broken?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `isConnected()` just tells you whether you ever connected this `Socket.` If you hadn't, you would be unable to get the output stream, so the `isConnected()` call would be unreachable. It doesn't tell you whether the *connection* is still *alive.* Similarly, `isClosed()` only tells you whether you have ever closed this `Socket.` Again, you haven't, otherwise you would be unable to get the output stream. It doesn't tell you whether the *peer* has closed. Also, you should use the same `ObjectOutputStream` for the life of the socket, not create a new one for every keepalive.

Comment: What is the advantage of using the same ObjectOutputStream every time instead of creating a new one?

Comment: The advantage is that it works. If you use a new one each time you have to use a new ObjectInputStream correspondingly at the peer, and you are likely to get this out of sync.

Comment: Each time I read a new Object I create a new ObjectInputStream as well. So they should not go out of sync, or should they?

Comment: If I re-use the ObjectOutputstreams on one side, I get a "StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header" exception at the second written Object. It seems to really be a bug in Android on the devices, because on the Emulator it runs.

Comment: No it isn't, it is a bug in your code. You have to *either* use a new `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` per object *or* use the same pair for the life of the connection. Not a mixture of both: and only the latter is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

After you send the keep-alive segment, TCP will retransmit after no acknowledgements are received, and after enough of these, will report an error to the calling application.

It is possible to confirm the continued existence of an inactive connection by sending 0 length messages that just trigger an ACK. This is similar to the OS level keep-alive functionality available on some platforms, but can be tuned to the application required frequency.

Comment: Yes I see some retransmits in Wireshark, but even after 2 minutes, I don't get an exceptions. 
Do I have to call some function to get the error?

Comment: The last segment should contain the FSH and/or RST flags set indicating the session is being torn down.

If you periodically call send() with a 0 length segment, it will fail with a socket closed exception. Ensure you have a non-buffered writer - the writer may otherwise not forward the request to the socket as it appears to have no effect.

Comment: It is not possible to send zero-length messages in TCP.

Comment: I'd disagree. Whether the underlying transport then sends a message as a user-level keep-alive may be open, but the interface definitely supports this. My response was vague as I had not checked whether the Java API provided for explicit keep-alive and suggested the empty message alternative. The OPs observation is indicative of a session with no timeout, not of any error.

Comment: Looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int), the `write()` method is constrained by "If `off` is negative, or `len` is negative, or `off+len` is greater than the length of the array `b`, then an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown." I don't see any restriction that prevents `len` from being zero.